# Reading data from excel to query database

Tags: java, database

I am not exactly sure what the best approach here is.  I am a novice programmer, trying to learn Java and I have a task I would like to complete.    I have data in a Excel file.   The Excel file has multiple columns.   I need to take a the value from a particular column, use it to query a database.  If the query returns null then add a value to a column, or mark it some how.  If the the query returns a value then do nothing.   Move to the next line.

anyone want to throw a noob a bone?

Comment: You better start by reading this [tutorial about apache poi](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/)

Answer (score 1):

See this. This is the answer I think. 
http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for extracting the data from the excel file and [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org) for database mapping/interaction.

Of course we can't write the code for you, but those two resources should give you a kickstart. Once you start writing the code, and you find yourself struggling, then I would post back here with code examples of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) jar,

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(READ_PARTICULAR_SHEET);

for (Row readRow : sheet)
{
    for (Cell readCell : readRow)
    {
       if (readCell.getCellType() == ANY_THING)
       {
         //anything you want
       }
    }
}
```

For reference [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/examples/HSSFReadWrite.java)